# How to get current master page and replace it on the Site using javascript

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery, custom-masterpage

I am using SharePoint 2013 Online and I'm looking for some JavaScript and html to get **current master page** for the site and change the same with other master page.

If anyone could help or just point myself in the correct direction it will be a help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

To get current master page, make a GET request to following end-point

```
/_api/Web?$select=CustomMasterUrl,MasterUrl
```

To change current master page, see [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/472cc1/changing-master-page-through-csom-in-sharepoint-2013/).

```
function MastePageChange() {
    var clientcontext;
    var cweb;
    var customMasterURL = '/_catalogs/masterpage/NewMasterPage.master';
    clientcontext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    cweb = clientcontext.get_web();
    cweb.set_customMasterUrl(masterPageUrl);
    cweb.set_masterUrl(masterPageUrl);
    cweb.update();
    clientcontext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
        alert("Master Page has been changed successfully \n" + customMasterURL);
    }, function(sender, args) {
        alert("Error: " + args.get_message());
    });
}

MastePageChange();
```

Comment: The code to change current master page provided on your link is working first time only but on page refresh it gives me an error that "File not found" .

Comment: Did u include `.master` with file name. I mean url should look like `/_catalogs/masterpage/NewMasterPage.master`. See the updated code

Comment: yes i have changeed it. for the first time the code works fine. but on page refresh it gives an error

Comment: and  `cweb.set_customMasterUrl(masterPageUrl);`  this also gives me an error that `masterPageUrl` not initialsize so I replace it with `customMasterURL`

Comment: It should work. I am using in my project. Check the master page url again.

Comment: Thanks Atish. It works now for custom pages. but gives an error while opening a list

Comment: That is fine! Now accept the answer. I got a down vote when you said it does not work!!